# Round Up the value to lowest in microsoft excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am writing a formula in excel in which I am diving 2 numbers and I don't want value in decimal.

I tried using ROUND(5/10,0) but it round of 0.5 to 1.

But my requirement is (0-0.99) should be evaluated as 0.

Similarly (2-2.990 should be evaluated as 2.

E.g.

- (5/10)   - 0 (output)
- (15/10)  - 1 (output)
- (25/10)  - 2 (output)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm a bit handicapped with an Excel version in Dutch, but I would think FLOOR would give you the outcome you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `ROUNDDOWN`.

Example:

`ROUNDDOWN(15/10,0)`

The second parameter stands for the precision. Zero means that you won't have any decimal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INT` to find the next lower integer.

- `=INT(5/10)` gives `0`
- `=INT(15/10)` gives `1`
- `=INT(25/10)` gives `2`
- `=INT(-1/10)` gives `-1` (because -1 is the integer which is **lower** than -0.1)
- `=INT(-15/10)` gives `-2` (for a similar reason)

Answer (score 1):

Use `INT()` or `FLOOR()` function to do that...

```
=INT(A1)
```

or

```
=FLOOR(A1,1)
```

If you want to use directly, then use as `=INT(5/10)` or `=INT(15/10)` ...etc.
In case of `=Floor()` function use as `=FLOOR(5/10,1)` or `=FLOOR(15/10,1)` ... etc